# Can't load a dll file in R using dyn.load windows 7 64bit

Tags: c++, windows, r, dll

Although similar questions have been asked I can't seem to find the answer to mine. I need to include C++ code into R to speed up my algorithm. After my first attempts of understanding how it works failed, I am following [this tutorial](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/stuff_for_blog/AlanRPackageTutorial.pdf). I use dev C++ which should have the right compiler gcc(I learned that I should not be using virtual C++) and have succesfully created the .dll file that he is talking about in 1.3.2. However when i try loading it in R (64bit) I get the error message

> Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
>         unable to load shared object 'C:/Rpackages/Test/src/Xdemo.dll':
>         LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I learned from other posts that this could due to the fact that in my path there is some calling to 32bit applications. However I removed these, but still get the same error. My path:

> C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.1\bin;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\MinGW\bin;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Users\anne\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;C:\Users\anne\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\

Some help would be really appreciated!

Comment: That tutorial is from 2007. Nowadays, the cool kids use [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html).

Answer (score 0):

When I use 64bit R, the path is under ...R\R-'version'\bin\x64 (instead of \bin) and the problem goes away.

Try to use R --version to confirm.